# Try to get arrays to work

Tags: javascript

I am wondering why my arrays do not work. Am I doing something wrong? I have been trying a lot of different arrays but none work. Am I just missing something?

Expense system:
Write a program that asks for a user's travel expenses. It should ask for the expense name, then the amount. It should keep collecting expenses until the user leaves the input blank.

Any expense $100 and under should be approved automatically.
Any expense over $100 should not be approved automatically.

Total up the approved and unapproved expenses.

Display the approved expenses first. Then display the expenses that need manual approval.

Display the total approved expenses and the total "needs approval" expenses.

Thanks in advance!

```
//Variables
var expenseName;
var expensePrice;
var loopAgain = true;
var approvedExpenses = new Array();
var approvedExpensePrice = new Array();
var unApprovedExpenses = new Array();
var unApprovedExpensePrice = new Array();
var approvedExpenseTotal = 0;
var unApprovedExpenseTotal = 0;


while(loopAgain) {
  expenseName = prompt("What is the expense? - Type 'done' to end.");
  expensePrice = prompt("What is the price?");
  expensePrice = Number(expensePrice);
  if (expenseName === "done"){
    loopAgain = false;
  }


  for(var count = 0; count < approvedExpenses.length; count++){
    if (expensePrice < 100) {
      approvedExpenseTotal = approvedExpenseTotal + expensePrice;
      approvedExpenses[count] = expenseName;
      approvedExpensePrice[count] = expensePrice;
      }else {
        unApprovedExpenseTotal = unApprovedExpenseTotal + expensePrice;
        unApprovedExpenses[count] = expenseName;
        unApprovedExpensePrice[count] = expensePrice;
      }
  }
}

document.write("APPROVED EXPENSES:<br>");

for(var count = 0; count < approvedExpenses.length; count++){
      document.write(approvedExpenses[count] + ": ");
      document.write(approvedExpenses[count] + "\n");
    }

document.write("EXPENSES NEEDING MANUAL APPROVAL:<br>");

for(var count = 0; count < unApprovedExpenses.length; count++){
      document.write(unApprovedExpenses[count] + ": ");
      document.write(unApprovedExpenses[count] + "\n");
    }

document.write("TOTALS:<br>");

document.write("Total approved expenses: $" + approvedExpenseTotal + "<br>");
document.write("Total expenses waiting approval: $" + unApprovedExpenseTotal + "<br>");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? At the moment it mostly seems like you are asking someone to write your program - try rewriting your question to be about the problem that you are having with arrays instead.

Comment: I mean that when it goes to display, the is nothing there and the array will not work. I just want someone to tell me why it is not working so i can fix it. And no, I do not want someone to write it as the whole program is right in front of your eyes but something is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your program logic is a bit odd. =b The specific issue as to why nothing is displayed is that your arrays are empty.

And they are empty because your for loop doesn't run.

And your for loop doesn't run because the condition in your for loop is based on "`approvedExpenses.length`", which is always zero.

Try reading your code from top to bottom (the flow of execution) and picturing all the values of your variables. It should reveal why `approvedExpenses.length` is zero.

(also within your for loop, the way you're setting the values may end up overwriting existing values, since the counter always starts from 0, where there may be existing data)

Comment: Wow this helps a lot!